# time away from him and all that - supplement? Meaning and analysis?

Tags: semantics, supplementation

I came across this today morning:

> Was it that he wasn’t the only center of attention? That I was busy with my career? It didn’t seem to matter that I was doing it for our family. My efforts to connect with Rosalind not only failed but angered Archie, **time away from him and all that**.

Will the bold part be considered as an adjunct or a supplement. In my opinion it is a supplement, realised by a Noun Phrase. But what does it mean? A cause effect relationship?

Any other sentences like this?

I would appreciate if a grammatical analysis is presented here with good reference.

Answer (score 1):

"That I was busy with my career? It didn’t seem to matter that I was doing it for our family. My efforts to connect with Rosalind not only failed but angered Archie, [due to] time away from him and all that".

People just write like this.

This: *time away from him and all that* is not organically connected to the sentence via grammar. But *it is something you hear in speech when providing an explanation to someone*.

Another example:

- He just didn't want to attend the weekend away, [due to] "time away from his children and all that".
- They had been thinking about the problem for a while, [due to] issues with the family and all that.

I used **due to** but there are plenty of other ways to connect these phrases to the preceding clauses. "because of" would also work. In any event, it would not be a clause; it is just a phrase as there is no verb + predicate.

The only reference I have is my own sense of grammar.

Comment: Such constructs are very common in spoken English for giving a reason or circumstances e.g. (all made up by me) "And then I fainted, the heat and everything" or "I felt so sad, the waste of human life". You could insert a preposition or something similar.

Comment: @StuartF I think I accounted for situations like that. I said: it is something you hear in speech when providing an explanation to someone. Did you say something very different?

Answer (score 0):

With no answer so far. I will try to answer what I feel about it.

The bold part is a supplement. Semantically it gives reason. The bold part can be considered as a Verbless clause.